# jQuery UI Endless Loop when referencing a slider that doesn't exist

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, crash

If I do this the page hangs:
`var foo = $("#mySliderThatDoesntExist").slider("value");`

So you may wonder why reference a slider that doesn't exist? It's called from a function that's run on page load and when something changes on the page (server side generates the slider on page load).

I wouldn't have thought this would cause the whole page to freeze and consume all the RAM on the PC.

A bug perhaps? Latest stable jQuery & jQuery UI

Comment: you could try using `if (!$("#eleID").isEmptyObject()) $("#eleID").slider('value', x)`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to do it but I guess the workaround would be:

```
var $mySliderThatDoesntExist = $("#mySliderThatDoesntExist");
var foo = ($mySliderThatDoesntExist.length >= 1) ? $mySliderThatDoesntExist.slider("value") : 0;
```

Comment: Presume you mean shouldn't? Thanks, I realise this is what I have to do but I don't think jQuery UI should crash the browser if I don't!

Comment: Yes, "shouldn't" thanks, edited. Indeed, it's daft. Must be a bug.